# Backbone.js: difference between class inizialization - JSON Format

Tags: json, variables, backbone.js, syntax

I'm learning Backbone.js as I feel it will come handy for my projects.

I'm running thru different tutorials and I cant's find the difference and best declaration for a class like:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Andy',
        age: 25,
        occupation: 'Whatever...'
    }
});
```

Is it better to initialize a Class this way:

```
var me = new Person({name: 'Andy'});
```

or

```
var me = new Person({'name': 'Andy'});
```

Why should I use single quotes to set a variable? It takes more time, but what's best? What's right and why? 
I'm not sure if is only a JSON matter or if is a backbone matter as actually this is a matter of initialization and use of curly brackets.
In case I use `.set(var, value)` and the variable has no quotes backbone throws an error as is looking for a variable.

I tried looking in Backbone.js website and JSON website but can't find an answer to this.

Comment: NB: This *isn't* JSON (which is a data format) - this is a JavaScript object literal. The distinction matters here, because the rules are different - in JSON, double-quoted keys are required, but as @McGarnagle points out, neither double nor single quotes are required for JS object literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are being pedantic, then valid JSON requires the single-quotes for all keys.  JSLint, for example, will reject JSON without the quotes.

But in Javascript they are not needed, and most people leave them out (as you noted, it's more concise).  That is, unless you have reserved characters in the name like `-`, etc.  So for example, `{ name: 'Andy' }` is fine, but `{ first-name: 'Andy' }` will cause the parser to balk.

Comment: See my note on JSON above. Also, worth noting that unquoted reserved words are bad news too: `{ if: "spam" }` is a syntax error.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Got it. Even if it makes sense completely, I tried with if and it doesn't give me any error. It is possible?

Comment: it won't give you an error if you wrap it in quotes. Unquoted, most JS parsers will throw a syntax error